# C# I can't print variable text in other Form

Tags: c#, database

I trying to code program and I have two forms (Form1 is for loging and Form2 is empty for now, but I would like to print Logged: 'Name' + 'Surename' from DB).

I created class User which has Name and Surename (both public static strings) and method GetUserInfo() to get Name and Surename by user's Login. If I print User.Name + User.Surename in MsgBox after program checks login and password everything is ok, but after Form2 loads then

```
label1.Text = "User: " + User.name + " " + User.surename;
```

in method public Form2() shows just User: and nothing more.

Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string login = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*\*\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where login='" + login + "' AND password ='" + pass + "'", connection);

        connection.Open();


        SqlDataReader Reader = query.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            count += 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            form2.Show();

            User.GetUserInfo(login);

            MessageBox.Show(User.name + " " + User.surename);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Bad Login");
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = "User: " + User.name + " " + User.surename;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and User class:

```
    public class User
{
    public static string name { get; set; }
    public static string surename { get; set; }

    public static void GetUserInfo(string login)
    {


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*\*\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select FirstName, LastName from Users where login='" + login + "'", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();


            SqlDataReader Reader = query.ExecuteReader();

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                User.name = Reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                User.surename = Reader["LastName"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you called `GetUserInfo` on the load event of the second form?

Comment: No, just in Form1

Comment: I though if I store some data to variables of public class User that they will be available through all forms.

Comment: Yes, if it will be a static

Comment: They are declared like this: public static string name { get; set; } and public static string name { get; set; }

Comment: Ok then, can you show us the code

Comment: @MegaTron updated

Comment: You are just initializing form2 with `new Form2();` before the data has being loaded with `User.GetUserInfo(login);`. Initialize the form after you have gathered the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
User.GetUserInfo(login);    
this.Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

because you need first set values for `name` and `surename` and then use it.

In your case, you first show Form2 and then set values

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I've used your code and still nothing.

Comment: @skutik Ok, see my updates. Just move `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` in `if` block before using

Comment: @skutik Glad to have been of help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add public variables or properties to Form1 so that you can access them:

in Form1:

```
public User user; 
....
user.name = Textbox1.Text; 
user.surname = Textbox2.Text;
```

In your Form2:

```
Form frm = new Form1();
frm.ShowDialog();
label1.Text = "User: " + frm.user.name + " " + frm.user.surename;
frm.Dispose();
```

Comment: This not make sense because `name` and `surename` is a static

Comment: Well I assumed these are the variables he wants to get. however even if they are not, this is an example of how to access the variables of the other form as it is the main purpose of the question

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the label text in the constructor of `Form2`. At that point they don't have a value as you haven't read the data from the database yet, so the label will simply read:

> User:

It won't change until you update it's value again. You need to call a method on `Form2` to update the label text once the call to `User.GetUserInfo` has completed successfully.

```
    if (count == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();
        form2.Show();

        User.GetUserInfo(login);

        // Update the label text here

        MessageBox.Show(User.name + " " + User.surename);
```

or swap the order of getting the user information and constructing `Form2`:

```
    if (count == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();

        User.GetUserInfo(login);
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
```

Either way will work, the one you choose depends on what else you need to do with your forms.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I've used your code (2nd example) and still nothing.

Comment: @skutik yeah I missed moving the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you have is that you are creating **Form2** before the properties in the **User** class are filled.

This is why :

```
label1.Text = "User: " + User.name + " " + User.surename;
```

This is called inside the constructor of `Form2`. This means whenever you initialize this form with

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

all code in the constructor executes. 
So the label text will be set when creating the form.

`User.GetUserInfo(login);` is called after this, the data will be empty for `Form2` since the form is already created.

**A possible solution would be**

To set the label in the form2 loading event and call `User.GetUserInfo(login);` before `form2.Show();`

*or*

Calling `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` after `User.GetUserInfo(login);`